# Spring Boot throws exception when int field in mongodb model has null value in the database

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongoose

I have a situation when a user does not enter data for certain field I pass null as value for that int field to signify that no value was entered by the user like

```
{user: 'John',
 age: null}
```

but when I read such document in my Spring Boot application, when it encounters above document, throws

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter age must not be null!
```

Is null allowed value in mongodb or Spring Boot is doing something wrong?

I tried to:

```
@Data
@Document
public class User {
    final private String user;
    @org.springframework.lang.Nullable    
    final private int age;
}
```

But it makes no difference. How to solve this problem other than not storing null ( because null is already populated in another node/mongoose application (which gladly stores and reads null values without any issue) using the same mongodb database?

Comment: What are u seeing if you change `age` as `Integer` instead of `int` ?

Comment: I replaced int with Integer and it fixed the problem. Not sure why it did not work with int. thank you

Comment: added explanation below, accept if that worked for you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `int` with `Integer` since `int` is a primitive type which won't accept `null` values. `Integer` is a wrapper object that accepts `null` values.